# check for required php-extensions

Tags: php, php-extension, prerequisites

I was asking myself if it is possible to check php files for required extensions like php-gd or php-xml. I'd like to identify all prerequisites to run a certain script.

I hope anyone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
christian

Comment: See http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extension_loaded`](https://www.php.net/extension_loaded):

```
if(extension_loaded('gd'))
{
    echo 'GD Library found';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`get_loaded_extensions()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php), which will return an array.

Comment: For this solution I would have to know which extension is required and then can check if it is loaded, right? I'd like to do it the other way around. I don't know which extensions are required to run the code and that's what I like to find out so I can install them.

Comment: You cannot achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
        echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
    }

    if (extension_loaded('xml')) {
        echo "PHP XML installed on your web server";
    }
?>
```

See also

```
<? print_r(get_loaded_extensions());?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhpCodeAnalyzer](https://github.com/wapmorgan/PhpCodeAnalyzer) to static analyze your code to finds usage of PHP extensions.